# How do I fit an image to a fixed size box using pythonMagick in python

Tags: python, imagemagick

```
try:
    original = PythonMagick.Blob(data)
    image = PythonMagick.Image(original)
except Exception as e:
    raise errors.UnknownFileFormat()

medium = PythonMagick.Blob()
small = PythonMagick.Blob()
large = PythonMagick.Blob()
largesize = "128X128"
mediumsize = "64X64"
smallsize = "48X48"

image.scale(largesize)
image.write(large)
image.scale(mediumsize)
image.write(medium)
image.scale(smallsize)
image.write(small)
```

Now, what I need is to create a base image of each of the sizes and overlay these images on top of it. So that when I show display in an img tag with fixed width and height, the browser does not stretch them. The lack of documentation is aggravating me.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably achieve what you are trying to do in CSS by `background-size:cover` or `background-size:contain` and `background-position:...;`. May be more complicated if trying to do other things.